# Si ejecuto un segundo stored procedure dentro del primer stored procedure, ¿el primero espera a que termine el segundo?

Tags: stored-procedure, sql-server-2008

Lo que pasa es que quiero enviar un parámetro de tipo tabla a un procedimiento almacenado que se llama dentro del cuerpo de otro procedimiento almacenado.

El segundo proceso toma un poco más de tiempo por eso quería saber si el primero espera al segundo.

Comment: no puedes hacer uno solo,escribe tu codigo °

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que el segundo toma más tiempo? ¿Hiciste algún tipo de benchmark? ¿Puedes dar más contexto de lo que estás haciendo por favor?

Comment: el primero lo que hace es insert o update a varias tablas los registros aveces son mas de 10 mil toma aprox 30seg y los errores se almacenan en una tabla temporal que lo recorro y junto las filas en una sola con formato html y  el segundo se encarga de recibir los datos de error y enviar un correo a los responsables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente el primer procedimiento almacenado *espera* a que termine la ejecución del segundo.

En general, en una base de datos SQL, la ejecución de un programa es secuencial. Hay motores (y SQL Server es uno de ellos) que ejecutan en paralelo muchas operaciones, por ejemplo, para resolver una consulta, pero está garantizado que un bloque TSQL se ejecutará de manera secuencial, es decir, una instrucción se ejecutará hasta que ha terminado de ejecutarse la anterior.

Es fácil comprobarlo creando dos *stored procedures* como estas:

```
create procedure Segundo as 
begin
  print convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) + ' Inicia el segundo';
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';  //una espera artificial...
  print convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) + ' Termina el segundo';
end;
go

create procedure Primero as 
begin
  print convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) + ' Inicia el primero';
  exec Segundo;
  print convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) + ' Termina el primero';
end;
go
```

La llamada a Primero

```
exec Primero;
```

Produce una salida como esta:

```
2016-12-01 09:36:49.640 Inicia el primero
2016-12-01 09:36:49.640 Inicia el segundo
2016-12-01 09:36:54.647 Termina el segundo
2016-12-01 09:36:54.647 Termina el primero
```